# How to get rid of #temp tables from the query

Tags: sql

I have three queries that put data in their respective #temp tables. Later, In one query those #temp tables are used again to get the data.

i.e

```
select {some columns} into #temp1 from {some tables} where {conditions1}
select {some other columns} into #temp2 from {some tables} where {conditions2}
select {some other columns} into #temp3 from {some tables} where {conditions3}

select {some columns from all #temp tables} from #temp1, #temp2, #temp3 where {conditions}
```

I want to get rid of these #temp tables and want to run last query without those #temp tables.

Any thought!!!

How about writing three different functions and putting all three query in those functions and calling functions from the third query!!

Thanks

Jai

Comment: Why exactly would you want to get rid of #temp tables? Is this a whole query or there are other statements? Is there anything between three select into statements and select from #temp tables? If so, does those statements do anything with #temp tables? How many rows does #temp tables usually have? What are "some conditions" at the end? All those questions (and more) could influence whatever #temp tables are good choice or not and what would best alternative be.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, Orders man, Orders. These are dummy queries but exactly same...I can't put my queries here. There are nothing between three select into statements. These statements just put data into #temp tables. There is not such a fix number. Its like some condition that we put in where clause.

Comment: like a `UNION` but you need a common schema between your sub queries. How are `#temp1`, `#temp2` and `#temp3` related?

Comment: @Jodrell, Yes, there are few common columns in all three #temp tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using MSSql, use CTE

```
;with cte1 as (
    select {some columns} from {some tables} where {conditions1}
), 
cte2 as (
    select {some other columns} from {some tables} where {conditions2}
),
cte3 as (
    select {some other columns} from {some tables} where {conditions3}
)
select {some columns from all ctes} from cte1, cte2, cte3 where {conditions}
```

this should run faster as there is no need to insert data into temp table.

another advantage of avoiding temp table is, using temp table sometimes has really bad impact on performances, as there is only one tempdb for entire sql server and heavily use tempdb, may block other queries. just google temp table and performance impacts, you will find a lots of article on this topic