# Error, while running one query in only one of the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query which is working in all databases except one. And the DB where it is not running giving below error.

```
[Error] Script lines: 1-7 --------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near '('. 

 More exceptions ... Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Below is the query

```
SELECT onecolumn, secondcolumn FROM one_table WHERE {someConditions}
AND someColumn NOT IN (select value from otherDB.dbo.functionName((select someList
from otherDB..otherDBTable where {someConditions}),','))
```

Any idea why its happening...Its really frustrating.

Thanks

Jai

Comment: That query shouldn't work in **any** of your databases, due to the unnecessary comma.

Comment: funcitonName ?? or functionname..typo?

Comment: @MarkBannister, Its working.

Comment: @sudmong, Its funcitonName only in other DB

Comment: @MarkBannister, Yes You are right...Actually there were three columns in first SELECT. While making dummy query, I forgot to remove the second comma.

Comment: I suspect that in turning your real query into the dummy query, you may have removed the cause of the problem. One possibility stands out: does `otherDB.dbo.functionName` take a different set of parameters in the problem database, than in all the others?

Comment: @MarkBannister, No, its taking same set of parameter is all DBs.

Comment: In which case, can you include the whole of the real query, together with the create script for the function? I don't see how we can attempt to answer this question, otherwise.

Comment: @MarkBannister, I cant really post my real query and function but there is one more COLUMN in first SELECT and in curly braces I have 2/3 conditions ,so to make it short I put it in {}, Thats the only difference between real and dummy. 
As you can see the function is taking 2 parameters, first is the RESULT of another SELECT statement and second is COMMA(,).

Comment: @MarkBannister, To be more precise the below one giving my above error.

select value from otherDB.dbo.funcitonName((select someList
from otherDB..otherDBTable where {someConditions}),',')

Comment: Problematic database probably has [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) set to 80.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, How to undo this or what it should be by default??

Comment: The Default value is 110..set it to 110 and the above query is working perfectly fine...Thanks a TON @NikolaMarkovinović. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please read [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) to see the changes because now something else might not work properly (probably not, but you should check anyway).

Comment: Yeah, I remember, I had to set it to 80 for something. Now I forgot what was that. I'll have to run my all queries once again..But I'll surely read the documentation..thanks again.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, I had to set it to 80 to run one of my Common Table Expressions (CTE) query to get rid of #temptables OR I am using LEFT OUTER join in WHERE clause. For more info please have a look of my post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015006/how-to-get-rid-of-temp-tables-from-the-query". Someone has suggested to use CTE. .Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, CTEs were introduced in Sql Server 2005 (Compatibility level 90). They will certainly work in 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You have one comma to many in the SELECT part, it should be like this:

```
SELECT onecolumn, secondcolumn FROM one_table WHERE {someConditions}
AND someColumn NOT IN (select value from otherDB..dbo.funcitonName((select someList
from otherDB..otherDBTable where {someConditions}),','))
```

Comment: Actually there were three columns in first SELECT. While making dummy query, I forgot to remove the second comma.

Comment: @Jai Great I could help! If this solved the problem would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: I would love to but my question is still not answered...My current post is My Question. Previous one was wrong post, you can say.

Comment: @Jai Oh didn't really notice that, my bad^^

Comment: To be more precise the below query is giving above mentioned error. 
select value from otherDB.dbo.funcitonName((select someList
from otherDB..otherDBTable where {someConditions}),',')