# How to get rid of #temp tables and CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, left-join, common-table-expression

As such I have asked one question on how to get rid of #temp tables.

[How to get rid of #temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015006/how-to-get-rid-of-temp-tables-from-the-query/16016076#16016076)

And got resolved too.. But I don't want to use CTE as well.

Any thought, how to merge all these queries into one.

```
select {some columns} into #temp1 from {some tables} where {conditions1}
select {some other columns} into #temp2 from {some tables} where {conditions2}
select {some other columns} into #temp3 from {some tables} where {conditions3}

select {some columns from all #temp tables} from #temp1, #temp2,
#temp3 where {conditions}
```

Thanks

Jai

Comment: Without the table scripts, desired columns, WHERE and JOIN conditions, we can't really help

Comment: @gbn, totally agree...but I can't really post my queries here. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I have solved it...but I am getting some other exception on the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally unclear to me what you want to achieve, but if you don't want to use CTEs (for whatever bizarre reasons), a derived table might do what you want:

```
select {some columns 
from ( 
  select {some columns} 
  from {some tables} 
  where {conditions1}
) as t1
  join ( 
    select {some other columns} 
    from {some tables} 
    where {conditions2}
  ) as t2 ON {join condition between t1 and t2}
  join (
    select {some other columns}  
    from {some tables} 
    where {conditions3}
  ) as t3 ON {join condition between t2 and t3}
where {conditions}
```

(although technically there isn't a real difference, this is just a different way to write the same thing)

Comment: you are are right...its just a another way to write CTE stuff...But I think, I cant use this too..I want to write single query for the same.