# Do we need WRITE access to DataBase to use CTE(Common Table Expressions)

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a requirement of not using #tempTables in my query because in future we are not going to have write access to intended DB. So I have replaced my #tempTables with CTE. But I am still doubtful whether it will  work in that situation or not.

So could you please tell me that, Does CTE require WRITE access to DB or not?

[Please refer my earlier post for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015006/how-to-get-rid-of-temp-tables-from-the-query/16016076#16016076)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (Although I doubt there is any DBMS that would need write access when using CTEs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes Oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a CTE is simply a SQL construct that allows you more power and flexibility in your queries

Or

No. A CTE consists only of SELECTS therefore no write access is needed: no implied or explicit CREATE, no INSERT or UPDATE

Comment: Hey @gbn, Any idea about using INDEXES on CTE? If yes, then how. I am using below code that is not working.
;with CTE1 as(
 SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table
),
CTE2 as (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 from otherTable
)
create index index1 on CTE1 (col1, col2, col3) 
create index PSIXNSRTTable on CTE2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select {few cols} from CTE1, CTE2

Because earlier I was creating indexes on my #tempTable with few columns in it.

Comment: @Jai: you can't create indexes in a CTE. You have to use the base table indexes

Comment: Yeah, I was getting error on the same though..just asked. Thanks.